# 404 - File Not Found Controller or its method is not found: \App\Controllers\Signup\New\Home::getIndex

Tags: php, codeigniter, backend

I get this error

```
404 - File Not Found
```

This is the code of the controller:

```
    <?
    
    namespace App\Controllers;
    
        class Signup extends BaseController
        {
        
            public function getNew()
            {
                return view("Signup/new");
            }
        }
```

I can't understand why it doesn't work, also another controller work fine.

In case, this is the view file:

```
    <?= $this->extend("layouts/default") ?>

<?= $this->section("title") ?>Signup<?= $this->endSection() ?>

<?= $this->section("content") ?>

<h1>Signup</h1>

<?php if (session()->has('errors')) : ?>

    <ul>
        <?php foreach (session('errors') as $error) : ?>
            <li><?= $error ?></li>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </ul>
<?php endif ?>


<?= form_open("/signup/create") ?>

<div>
    <label for="name">Name</label>
    <input type="text" name="name" id="name" value="<?= old('name') ?>">
</div>

<div>
    <label for="password">Password</label>
    <input type="password" name="password">
</div>

<div>
    <label for="password_confirmation">Repeat password</label>
    <input type="password" name="password_confirmation">
</div>

<button>Sign up</button>
<a href="<?= site_url("/") ?>">Cancel</a>

</form>

<?= $this->endSection() ?>
```

[image: And this is the an image of the files]

Codeigniter version 4.2.1

Comment: Share your router file

Answer (score 0):

Since v4.2.0, the new more secure Auto Routing has been introduced.

When no defined route is found that matches the URI, the system will attempt to match that URI against the controllers and methods when Auto Routing is enabled.

In Routes.php comment out setAutoRoute and set it to true;

```
$routes->setAutoRoute(true);
```

or define a route to the Controller.